# Restart agent thread-pool after calling shutdown-agents

Tags: clojure, threadpool, agent

If I call (shutdown-agents) from the REPL, and then later on try to use an agent later on, I get an exception saying the agent pool isn't available (of course!).  The question is, how can the agent thread pool be re-started without having to re-launch the REPL and lose all of my state?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shutdown-agents` is meant to be run before you exit the JVM.  As far as I know, you can't restart them afterward.  See e.g. [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_frm/thread/c52bba91357261f6/e397dc4d3ce17653) and [here](http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2010-04-12.html#10:37).